# Why wont the trigger enter function work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Despite searching online, I haven't been able to use the OnTriggerEnter function.

Hi, ive been programming a project over the last 2 days in Unity 3D. For the project, I need a game object to spawn when a bullet collides with the floor (cube). I have a script on the floor, and the bullet is a prefab with the needed tag. Below is the code I used

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hit)
    {
        if (hit.gameObject.tag == "seed1")
        {
            Debug.Log("Ooga");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Does this help from the help for `OnTriggerEnter`? "Note: Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component."

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: [Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) provides a better overview over which events will be fired depending on the two objects components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the entering object has:

- A Collider
- A Rigid Body

The Object with the trigger:

- Has a Collider that is set to Trigger